# Parcel Editor 10.0 Selection

Tags: standard-license-level, parcel

I am trying out the ArcEditor 10.0 trial version and am having problems with the Parcel Editor.  I am attempting to "select" using SELECT PARCEL FEATURE tab, nothing gets selected.  I did the START EDITING under Parcel Editor, clicked SELECT PARCEL FEATURE, tried selecting the parcel features to no avail.  After I click the SEL PAR FEATURE, it does show that features symbol on the pointer/scroll arrow.

When I click START EDITING, only the SEL PAR FEATURE is clickable, the rest of the other PARCEL EDITOR buttons are unclickable.

I am using shp files I created while using 9.3 ArcView.  Would that have anything to do with it (which I can't see any reason why it should)?

Some guidance in resolving this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Have you managed to fix this? i have the same problem, but can't figure out what's wrong

Comment: No I have not fixed it.